# Performing join operation on two huge tables using apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 tables in my database. Each table is having 100 million rows.

Is there a way to join these 2 tables and extract data using apache spark in fastest way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the most efficient way would be to use DataFrames and call `join`, followed by any other criteria. The benefit is that certain filters or selections will be pushed as far down as possible to cut down your network load...only the data that is needed will be pulled.

Without more information, that is the best suggestion I can give.

Comment: _any filters_ is a serious overstatement :)

Comment: @zero323 I had thought that as far as possible would cover it, but I changed it to be certain instead of any